# WinRT ProgressBar Value Binding not updating

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

In Windows 8 RP I converted a XAML view to a more MVVM like model.

The Binding to the ProgressBar.Value property seems not to update the value. RaisePropertyChanged was sent correctly, othere Parameter like .Maximum and .Visibility seems to work correctly.
The value is updated via a DispatchTimer in the ViewModel class.

Anyone encountered this with "Metro Style Apps"?

Some snippet:

```
Time = 1;
MaxTime = 60;
TimerVisibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
timer.Start();
```

The ProgressBar is Collapsed before setting the above values.

Comment: Next time please show the actual xaml and C# code.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, fixed it. The Binding Mode should be set to "TwoWay". Strange  why is it not the Default mode?

Comment: A progressbar is more or less readonly from the UI point of view.

Comment: If you add the code I might be able to tell you what's going on.